# C# IF statement about a int check vs string in a DataTable

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable where I have a column "Number" number is a string.
I would like to do

```
if (row["Number"].ToString() >= 1 && row["Number"].ToString() <= 100)
```

So if the column number is higher than 1 or lower than 100 do this.
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this. Google for "convert string to number".

Comment: What do you mean by _"Number" number is a string._? If your column is _number_, why it is a string type?

Comment: @Abhi that's so janky.  I don't recommend comparing strings that represent numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the `string` into an `int` by using [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int rowNumber;
if (!int.TryParse((string)row["Number"], out rowNumber)
{
   // Not an int
}

if (rowNumber >= 1 && rowNumber <= 100)
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I get :cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: @Akjell Sorry, forgot the cast.

Comment: I will check now had to use .ToString() on my row

Comment: If `row` isn't a string, the cast will fail while `ToString` will simply produce the string representation of the object. I'm assuming that `row["Number"]` is always a string.

Comment: Yes, if(!int.TryParse(row["Number"].ToString(), out rowNumber)), works but not sure if this will help me. What I want to do in the If statement is row.SetField("Number", ""); I want to remove number where it is >1 and <100.

Comment: Remove the number from the row? That's not what you asked in your question.

Comment: What I asked was if (row["Number"].ToString() >= 1 && row["Number"].ToString() <= 100) then in the statement row.SetField("Number", ""); that would work if it was possible to do what I asked.

Comment: But yea its a bit messy they need to be in string it get exported later on and needs to be strings.

Comment: @Akjell - If row is a DataRow, you should use the `Field` method to get the value:  `if (!int.TryParse(dr.Field<string>("Column"), out rowNumber))`  This is an extension method so be sure you have a reference to the _System.Data.DataSetExtensions_ assembly.